# Android share image with text to Viber and Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, android-studio, share, viber, action-send

Is it any way to share Image with Text same time with same "Intent.ACTION_SEND" to Viber or Facebook Messenger?
I have code, but it send only Image without the text.
Is it possible to send Image + Text with same ACTION_SEND?
It works good with e-mail share, or SMS share, both image and text sharing, but in Viber or Facebook, only Image sharing.
Can somebody give me working solution how to fix it?

Thank You very much.

Activity:

```
package com.my.game;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class shareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button share;
ImageView imageView;

static Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

    share = findViewById(R.id.shareTestButton);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.shareimage);

    activity = this;

    // initialising text field where we will enter data


    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Now share image function will be called
            // here we  will be passing the text to share
            // Getting drawable value from image
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            shareImageandText(bitmap);
        }
    });
}

private void shareImageandText(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Uri uri = getmageToShare(bitmap);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\nI Am Rich Pro - Luxury Boss \n\n" +
            "I am a member of the billionaire club. My Rich Level: 3/5\n\n" +
            "Download now:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.game \n\n"+
            "Can you beat my rich level? Proove it!");
    i.setType("image/*");

    shareActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));

}

// Retrieving the url to share
private Uri getmageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagefolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        imagefolder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(imagefolder, "shared_image.png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.thedgames.iamrich.fileprovider", file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return uri;
}
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".shareActivity">

<!-- Here we will attach our image to share -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shareimage"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/silver_card" />

<!-- We will click on it then shareonlytext
     function will be called-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/shareTestButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Click here to Share "
    android:textSize="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".shareActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"/>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.my.game.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: `ACTION_SEND` is only documented to support either text or a stream, not both in a single `Intent`. What apps do when you supply both is up to the app developers.

Comment: Ok thanks, btw there are solution to add description to image in Viber? Because i share maually image in Viber, there are option to set description? Is it any way to add description to image programmatically? Thank you

Comment: You might see if Viber has a dedicated API for sharing content, beyond `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i contacted Viber dev support. I searched a lot but i did not found any solution. I will re-think my game share function, maybe share image and text seperated in different "Action_send"...